# file_get_contents() skipping text between <> tag

Tags: php, file-get-contents, csv

I am trying to read a .tsv file using PHP. I am using the simplest method of  `file_get_contents()` but it is skipping any text between `<>` tags.
Following is the format of my .tsv file

```
<id_svyx35_88c_avbfa5>  <Kuldeep_Raval> rdf:type    <wikicat_Delhi_Daredevils_cricketers>
```

Following is the code I am using

```
$filename = "access_s.tsv";
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
//Split file into lines
$lines  = explode("\n", $content);
echo $content;
```

On reading it, the output is just

```
rdf:type
```

Please help in what can be the solution to read the line as it is?

Comment: what's the output of `echo $content`  ?

Comment: View the page source. I bet you see in the there. Thje browser is trying to display that content as tags.

Comment: the whole thing is there, since they are xml tags, your browser is just hiding them, if you look at the source you'll see it's all there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply `htmlspecialchars()` to `$content`:

```
$filename = "access_s.tsv";
$content = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($filename));
//Split file into lines
$lines  = explode("\n", $content);
echo $content;
```

[Reference on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

The tags have always been there, the browser just does not show them. Just like with any valid HTML tag, you can see them when viewing the source code of the website.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives rise to another problem, if now I want to use $lines for putting row data into database, it removes the property of TSV too. That is the tabs are also removed. Which creates a headache to parse the file. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some example? What exactly happens, and which values are you trying to parse?

Comment: if you see the given example of a tsv row. I want to parse all the four tab separated values and store them correspondingly in their respective columns in a MYSQL database. But if I use your solution, parsing would become difficult as the tabs are also being removed from the line.